# Read source code with PHP

Tags: php, html, http

Is there away to read a source code from another site?
Source code as HTML, when you right click on a site and then "Source code".

I've tried:

```
<? $f = fopen ("http://www.example.com/f", r);
echo $f;
?>
```

It did not work. How do I do this?

Comment: How didn't your posted code work?

Comment: @Kevin: Because `f` is a reference to the opened file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
<?php
$f = file_get_contents("http://www.site.com/f");
echo $f;
?>
```

Comment: Change `echo $f` to `echo htmlspecialchars( $f )` and you'd view the actual source. Of course this all assumes that `allow_url_fopen` is enabled in ini.

Comment: Nick Weaver and Kevin Peno Thanks! This is what I was looking for! I'm grateful! I can't thank you enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use curl to grab the remote HTML, and when printing I'd be sure to sanitize it so the viewing browser doesn't try to render or execute script. (after all, you can't guarantee to control the contents of the remote HTML - it could be malicious)

Alternatively you could use shell commands to grab it to a temporary file, and read that file in. Wget or the curl binary itself could be prodded into doing this for you. (wget -O /tmp/sometempfile http://www.site.com/f) but note this is dangerous, and might set off "alarms" for sysadmins watching the system. Calling wget et al and dumping in /tmp/ is generally the first thing someone tries to do when they break into a PHP application.

Comment: He was using fopen to download a website, I think your answer will only stand to confuse him.

Answer (score 1):

That all depends on what you qualify as "source". To grab the output from a site, you could use `curl`:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://www.google.ca');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
echo $data;
```

If you're talking about the server-side source of the page, then no, there's no way that you can do that (I hope that's not what you're talking about :))

Comment: don't forget to use `htmlspecialchars` to see the source rather than rendering it.

Comment: Demian Brecht@ I got this error "Call to undefined function curl_init()". What is the difference between this and the first one posted? Thanks a lot of helping :D

Comment: @muazam: You need to have the curl mod installed. Do a quick google search for installing curl on whatever platform you're using.

Answer (score 0):

For reading contents (source) of a remote page, at some other website:

```
<?php

$linktopage = "http://www.google.com/index.html";
$sourcecode = file_get_contents( $linktopage );
echo $sourcecode;

?>
```

Comment: How is this different from Nick's answer?

Comment: Considering the minimal time difference, it's not really a double post and the answer is correct :P

Comment: Nick's answer was at 3 points. It would be nice to avoid duplicates by looking at answered questions before answering.

Comment: Thanks it worked, but I think you forgot the htmlspecialchars function. :P