# Secure a SMTP password in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, email, phpmailer

I'm going to use the phpmailer class in my WordPress-plugin to support the use of SMTP in my e-mail function. Is it safe to store the password in the PHP code? I don't feel 100% comfortable with leaving my login there. So my questions: Is it safe enough? How can I easily make it more secure; should I hash it in a database or something? I know MD5 isn't really that secure, but I guess it is better than putting the password in the source code?

Comment: Is this for a distributed plugin or something you're only going to use on your site?

Comment: You are going to need to plain text password either way.

Comment: try storing it in database , hashed with [SHA1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php). its more safe

Comment: There was some article from Martin Fowler, where he said, that you can encrypt your password in your source code, and when checking out, then there is a decrypt script, which needs a password entered which then decrypts the password.

Comment: @sushant if it's hashed you can't pass it to another service for authentication.

Comment: Also @sushant even it it would be possible you should never ever use sha1 to hash passwords (just like md5)

Comment: @Machavity First of all for my own use, so then I might store it temporary in plain text in my PHP when I use it. But I might want to distribute the plugin later, as I find it to be quite useful and want to share it with others.

Comment: Adding to @Machavity 's (sic) comment, if it's a distributed plugin I'd hope you wouldn't be letting all and sundry use your SMTP account, but yeah if it's just on your site then there really isn't any point, plus I don't think it's even possible.

Answer (score 3):

Essentially you can't - and there are many posts on here saying exactly that. You can however obfuscate it to keep opportunists away. The most straightforward way is to put your password in an external config file (which helps you avoid obvious mistakes like checking your password into github). You can encrypt it to some extent, but at some point you need to decrypt it with some other supposedly secret key, so you're back at square one.

md5 and sha1 (or any other hashing function) have nothing to do with this question; hash functions are simply not applicable to this use case.

Answer (score 0):

Tons of sites store passwords inside PHP source code. If a password is stored inside `<?php ... ?>` tags, it can be considered secure.

PHP source code is rendered by the PHP engine before being exposed, which is a necessary security component. There is no known way to read it, unless your site itself has security vulnerabilities.

Sources:

[Possible to view PHP code of a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995360/possible-to-view-php-code-of-a-website)

http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum88/10926.html

[Read source code with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757316/read-source-code-with-php#answer-5757412)

http://www.vodahost.com/vodatalk/mysql-php/15061-php-source-code-php-files.html

Comment: There are other ways of leaking sensitive data besides simply reading the source. Simple example https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67206